# How to explain ANOVA output from a multiple regression?

Tags: r, anova, multiple-regression, interpretation

If I do a multiple regression such as:

```
df<-data.frame(y1=rnorm(100,2,3),
y2=rnorm(100,3,2),
x1=rbinom(100,1,0.5),
x2=rnorm(100,100,10))

fit<-lm(cbind(y1,y2)~x1+x2,data=df)
> anova(fit)
Analysis of Variance Table

            Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)  1 0.75423  147.306      2     96 <2e-16 ***
x1           1 0.00720    0.348      2     96 0.7069    
x2           1 0.00928    0.450      2     96 0.6391    
Residuals   97                                          
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I am wondering how to explain this ANOVA object where two models have different responses and the same set of predictors.

Answer (score 3):

The `x2` line looks at the added information by adding `x2` to the model above and beyond the intercept and `x1`; the `x1` line looks at adding `x1` to the intercept (ignoring `x2`) and the intercept line compares fitting an intercept to having the mean be 0.

In all cases the test is of whether the term aids in predicting all of the response variables jointly (assumes a multivariate normal distribution of the $y$s conditional on the $x$s).

[This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillai_trace) may be helpful as a starting place to learn more about the Pillai trace statistic and other options.